# MySQL FULLTEXT vs Postgres GIN

Tags: mysql, postgresql, inverted-index

If I understand correctly, it seems like both [`FULLTEXT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-fulltext-index.html#innodb-fulltext-index-design) and [`GIN`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/gin-intro.html) use an inverted-index as the basic data structure starting point. Are these two index types more-or-less equivalent, or what are the differences between the two?

Comment: Both databases are open source, so you can compare the implementation details of those index types.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I wouldn't even know where to start to be honest...Do you know where those implementations are in their respective repositories?